# HttpRequest middleware not catching all requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httprequest, middleware

In an Asp net core application the authorization is done by an API and I want to return to the login page once the response is not OK (200).

I'm trying to catch the HttpContext from a request to an API. My HttpClient is in a static class. I implement a middleware to catch all requests, but requests sent over the static ApiServices are not caught. With local requests is meant things like images or bootstrap from www folder.
It looks like the middleware cannot catch the httpclient created by the ApiServices.
For replication I created a new project with following code:

Program.cs

```csharp
 
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

//app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
app.UseRequestAuthorization();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

ApiServices.cs

```csharp
 public static class ApiServices
 {
     static readonly HttpClient httpClient;
     static readonly HttpClientHandler handler;

     static Uri Uri => new("https://localhost:7182");

     public static AuthenticateResponse? AuthenticateResponse { get; private set; }

     static ApiServices()
     {
         handler = new HttpClientHandler()
         {
             CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
             ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
             {
                 return true;
             }
         };

         httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
         {
             BaseAddress = Uri,
             Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
         };

         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "api.xxxxxxxx.com";
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     }
}

public static async Task<bool> LoginAsync(Credentials credentials)
{
    AuthenticateResponse = null;
    var url = $"/{Routes.AuthenticateRoute}/authenticate";

    var response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, credentials);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        AuthenticateResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthenticateResponse>();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticateResponse?.Token);
    }

    return AuthenticateResponse is not null;
}
```

And the middleware looks like that:

```csharp
     public class AuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) 
 {
     private readonly RequestDelegate _next = next;

     public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
     {
         if (context.Response.StatusCode==StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)
         {
             context.Request.Path = "/Home/Index";
             context.Request.Query = null;
         }

         await _next(context);
     }
 }

 public static class AuthorizationMiddlewareMiddlewareExtensions
 {
     public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestAuthorization(
         this IApplicationBuilder builder)
     {
         return builder.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
     }
 }
```

and the login page:

```csharp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using TurfManagerHelpers.Models;
using TurfManagerHelpers.Services;

namespace ApiServices_Test.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public Credentials Credentials { get; set; } = new();

        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        public string Message { get; set; } = "";

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet(string message = "")
        {
            Message = message;
        }

        public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostLoginAsync(Credentials credentials)
        {
            string? message;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                message = "ModelState is iinvalid!";

                return RedirectToAction("Get", new { message });
            }

            var loginSuccess = await ApiServices.LoginAsync(credentials);


            if (loginSuccess)
            {
                message = "you are logged in!";
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid login attempt.";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Get", new { message });
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or advice greatly appreciated.

The middleware is hit by requests like

```xml
     <img class="avatar" src="images/logos/V3/TurfManagerLogo_square.png" alt="Avatar">
```

or

```xml
     <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

but not

```csharp
    public static async Task<bool> LoginAsync(Credentials credentials)
{
    AuthenticateResponse = new();
    var url = $"/{Routes.AuthenticateRoute}/authenticate";
    var response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, credentials);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        AuthenticateResponse = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<AuthenticateResponse>();

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthenticateResponse?.Token);
    }
    return AuthenticateResponse is not null;
}
```

Basically I want to catch the request between this

```sharp
var response = await httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(url, credentials);
```

and this

```sharp
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
```

Answer (score 0):

MiddleWares would handle request that your current asp.net core app received,the request you send with httpclient to another .net core app(Web Api) would be handled with the middlewares in that app,would never be handled in your current app's middleware

And from your description:

> In an Asp net core application the authorization is done by an API and
> I want to return to the login page once the response is not OK (200).

The JWT token you received is intend to protect the resource in your webapi  not your current app(Razor Page),and you couldn't read the claims in the token and assign the ticket to httpcontext,HttpContext.User would always be null ,you're not really authenticated.

what you need is [Remote Authetication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#remoteauthenticationhandlertoptions-vs-authenticationhandlertoptions),you could check other concepts related with authentication in asp.net core either

You could configure like

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(op =>
{
    op.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    


})
// Use Cookie to hold the claims you received from remote server,you could use jwt token either
.AddCookie("Cookies")

.AddOAuth("Scheme1", op =>
{
  .......
  //set clientId,callbackpath.. follow the requirement you've mentioned here
    
})
```

Here's a full example in this [article](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/07/12/secure-your-aspnet-core-app-with-oauth)